# Importing CSV values into a webpage and including commas using split()

Tags: html, vba, csv, asp-classic

EDIT: I know similar questions like this have been asked on SO but nothing compares to how simple I need this to be :)

I have a classic-asp web page that reads a CSV file and spits it onto the page using HTML. The content in the CSV file however contains some paragraphs with properly formed sentences.

In short, I need to display the grammar of these paragraphs which includes commas.

This is a snippet of what my parsing looks like:

```
    sRows = oInStream.readLine
    arrRows = Split(sRows,",")

    If arrRows(0) = aspFileName And arrRows(1) = "minCamSys" Then
        minCamSys1= arrRows(2)
        minCamSys2= arrRows(3)
        minCamSys3= arrRows(4)
```

How can I alter my Split() so that I can display commas without breaking the CSV format.

I would prefer to use double quotes around the data that contains a comma (as is usually the CSV standard when importing to Excel). For example:

```
Peter,Jeff,"Jim was from Ontario, Canada",Scott
```

I would like to avoid the use of a library as this is a simple in-house application.

Thank you!

Comment: I know similar questions like this have been asked on SO but nothing compares to how simple I need this to be :)

Comment: Please add this comment to the question.

Comment: Another option is to use your csv file as if it were a database, you can connect to it with the OLEDB Jet driver, see this article.  What it doesn't make clear is that you use the csv file name as the name of your table.  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/connect-to-csv-data-files-using-microsoft-data-access-components.html

Comment: Thanks for the input @John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well folks the answer was right in front of my face. Kind of silly really but for this application, it will suffice.

I swapped out the , delimiter with a |. So the new code looks like this:

```
sRows = oInStream.readLine
arrRows = Split(sRows,"|")
```

This may not be a great solution but for this simple application it is all that is necessary.

Comment: Just a quick note - make sure you're not going to be using the bar character anywhere else.

Comment: I figured it's extremely uncommon in this application so I think that's the best character to use! Do you have any suggestions for an even less common character in an entirely text based web app?

Comment: No - if you're happy that this is not going to be used, then that's fine. I like to define a constant value to hold the delimiter character (`Const C_SEPARATOR = "|"` for instance), then you can change quickly and easily for everything.